# How to export datagridview into Open Office Excel c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, interop, .net-assembly, openoffice.org

I have a datagridview and i can export the same to Microsoft Excel. Now i want to export the datagridview to Open Office Excel. I cant figure out what assemblies are to be used in reference for my project for Open Office. For Microsoft Excel i used the following reference followed by the code of the event.

```
using Excel=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


private void exportToMSExcelToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
                app.Visible = true;
                worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
                worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                worksheet.Name = "Exported from .net app";
                for (int i = 1; i < datagridEC.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = datagridEC.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < datagridEC.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < datagridEC.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = datagridEC.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR--> " + ex.Message.ToString(), "ERROR");
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
```

This works fine for Microsoft Office but now i would like to replace it for Open Office Excel.

Comment: This file should work for Open Office. What is the error you get when you open it with Open Office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add references for following assembles: cli_basetype, cli_cppihelper, cli_oootypes, cli_ure, cli_uretypes

And also

```
using unoidl.com.sun.star.lang;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.bridge;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.frame;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.beans;
using UNO = unoidl.com.sun.star.uno;
using OOo = unoidl.com.sun.star;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.text;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.container;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.sheet;
using unoidl.com.sun.star.table;
```

And also example how to get a worksheet:

```
            UNO.XComponentContext context = uno.util.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
            XMultiServiceFactory SrvManager = (XMultiServiceFactory)context.getServiceManager();
            XComponentLoader loader = (XComponentLoader)SrvManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");

            string AFile = "file:///" + "filePath";

            PropertyValue[] props = new PropertyValue[0];

            XComponent oDoc = loader.loadComponentFromURL(AFile, "_blank", 0, props);

            XSpreadsheetDocument xSpreadDoc = (XSpreadsheetDocument)oDoc;

            XSpreadsheets xSheets = xSpreadDoc.getSheets();
            XIndexAccess xIA = (XIndexAccess)xSheets;

            XSpreadsheet xSheet = (XSpreadsheet)xIA.getByIndex(0).Value;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gleb. I got it. but i am having an issue regarding the assemblies. How to add them?